# How to rotate (after a 90 degrees rotation in x axis ) in the new coordinates on the y axis in openGL es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es

I'm rotation a cube 90 degrees in x axis, after that I want to rotate in another 90 degrees in y axis but it does get the expected(from me) result since it was rotated before
I'd like rotation to happen lets say in world coordinates ...  My current code I think is resetting the identity matrix but if I remove that line nothing renders.Here is my code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
//      GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(iProgId);

    cubeBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iPosition, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, cubeBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iPosition);

    texBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(iTexCoords, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(iTexCoords);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, iTexId);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(iTexLoc, 0);


    Matrix.setIdentityM(m_fIdentity, 0);


    if(rotating == true)
    {
        rotate();
    }

    Matrix.rotateM(m_fIdentity, 0, -xAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(m_fIdentity, 0, -yAngle, 1, 0, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(m_fVPMatrix, 0, m_fViewMatrix, 0, m_fIdentity, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(m_fVPMatrix, 0, m_fProjMatrix, 0, m_fVPMatrix, 0);
```

//      Matrix.translateM(m_fVPMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(iVPMatrix, 1, false, m_fVPMatrix, 0);

```
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
```

//      GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    }

Comment: Have you resolved this issue by yourself? Direct answer would probably be to multiply your rotation vectors with the inverse matrix of your current model matrix (where current model matrix must be at (0,0,0)). This will only lead to more and more questions so you should rethink your methods of defining your object's location and rotation in your scene... If you still want a discussion about it you can send me an email.

Comment: Could you turn you answer in some sample code please?. You said "multiply your rotation vectors with the inverse matrix of your current model matrix" , watching my code could you write some sample code?. Thank you

Comment: Representation of your rotation vectors are the last 3 parameters in rotateM method. Other then that you need some way to get inverted matrix (there's a lot of methods and samples on web) and a method to multiply a vector with it (also on web). On the other hand it just might work to create another matrix on witch you only apply rotations in opposite direction then your model (+xAngle, +yAngle) to get the inverted matrix.